# What's wrong with this face filling?

Tags: modeling, faces

Whenever I try to fill the face connecting the selected vertices (by selecting the edges and pressing <kbd>f</kbd>:
[image]

I get this weird filling
[image]

[image]

So, why isn't that face filled properly? and how can I fill it smoothly?

Comment: That's not just the failure of 'F' to create new edges spanning your new face ( which you would expect: either use Grid Fill or cut the replacement edges yourself ). Some of your edges are connecting the wrong vertices, somewhere inside the object, or doubles. Clean up, and check all the vertices on the perimeter of your hole.

Answer (score 3):

by selecting the edges and just pressing <kbd>F</kbd> you are creating a so-called n-gon (face with more than 4 vertices). The subdivision modifier can't handle those very well and thats what messing up your mesh.

[image]

Select the top and bottom row of vertices (1st image) and use grid fill to make the faces.

```
Mesh ‣ Faces ‣ Fill/Grid Fill
```

**Result on my mesh:** (your proportions are a bit different, but its basically the same structure):

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work, I get an error message saying that "loops are not connected by boundary edges"